# JS always loads default view

Tags: javascript, django

I'm taking the CS50 course "Web Programming with Python and Javascript".

In one of the projects that need to be done, one have to implement a social network platform where users can post some texts, like and dislike them and follow other users.

There are 3 routes a user can go:

- All posts,
- Following and
- users posts.

I've been trying to solve this with js front end. I've a function "view_posts", that takes an argument that specifies what posts should be fetched and rendered to the html page. Consider the following part of my js file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  username = document.getElementById('username').innerText
  document.querySelector('#posts').addEventListener('click', () => view_posts('all'));
  document.querySelector('#username').addEventListener('click', () => view_posts(username));
  document.querySelector('#following').addEventListener('click', () => view_posts('followers'));
  document.querySelector('#post-form').style.display = "none";

  view_posts('all')
});
```

Fetching the data is basically working, but js is always displaying the default view "view_posts('all')". Meaning, even if I click on the element whose id is #post, calling the very same function including the same argument, the function is called without displaying anything, before it calls the default view again (this time it will display the data correct).

```js
function view_posts(selector) {
  // document.querySelector('#post-form').style.display = "none";

  if (selector === 'all') {
    document.querySelector('#header').innerText = "All Posts";
    document.querySelector('#post-form').style.display = "block";
  } else if (selector == 'following') {
    document.querySelector('#header').innerText = "Following";
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#header').innerText = selector;
  }

  fetch(`/network/${selector}`)
    // .then(response => response.text())
    // .then(posts => console.log(posts))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(posts => {
      posts.forEach((element) => {
        var item = document.createElement('div');

        item.className = "card";
        item.innerHTML = `<div class="card-body" id="item-${element.id}">
    
            ${element.author} | ${element.timestamp}
            <br>
            ${element.body}
            </div>`;
        document.querySelector('#post-view').append(item);
        // document.getElementById('item-${element.id}').addEventListener('click', () => view_posts(element.author))
      });
    });
  // .catch(console.log.bind(console));
};
```

EDIT: here is my index.html

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}
<div id="post-view">
  <h2 id="header" style="margin:10px"></h2>
    <div id=post-form>
      <h4>New Post</h4>
      <form>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Type here..."></textarea>
        <input onclick="create_post()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post"/>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
<script src="{% static 'network/index.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Looks ok from a glance. Show the HTML with the elements you can click. Possibly it is a server issue. YOu should show that code too

Comment: @mplungjan yes, that hint was enough. I had href in the navigation bar, forcing to reload index.html every time. Pretty dumb. Anyways, that solves my problem. On the other hand, I have now the problem, that instead of displaying only the choosen posts (e.g. of a specific user), it will add them to the html every time I click on another view until I really reload the page (f5)

Answer (score 0):

To not append

```
document.getElementById('post-view').innerHTML = posts.map(element => (
  `<div class="card">
     <div class="card-body" id="item-${element.id}">
       ${element.author} | ${element.timestamp}<br>${element.body}
     </div>
   </div>`).join("");
```

Comment: well, I found a workaround for now:
document.querySelector('#post-view').innerHTML = "";

but where should I place your code snippet? Right after ".then(posts => {" ?

Comment: Yes, it replaces your posts.forEach